# The purpose of the file containing export directives

Tags: flutter

What is the purpose of the dart file containing the content like this? The file is located right in the lib folder and contains nothing more.

```
export 'src/admob.dart';
export 'src/admob_banner.dart';
export 'src/admob_banner_size.dart';
export 'src/admob_banner_controller.dart';
export 'src/admob_interstitial.dart';
export 'src/admob_reward.dart';
export 'src/admob_events.dart';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user of the library will be able to import just the single file and get all the classes and methods exported in it. Also, it's considered a bad practice to import anything from `src/*` directories, as they are considered to contain implementation details.

You can find more info in the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#organizing-a-library-package), specifically this point:

> Create a “main” library file directly under lib, lib/.dart, that exports all of the public APIs. This allows the user to get all of a library’s functionality by importing a single file.